# Fatal error: swift 2.3 when unwrapping value

Tags: swift, wcsession

I'm trying to send a saved string to the apple watch with WCsession methode. But when I do this I get an error in swift 2.3: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value !!

```
func Reloadip() {


    let ip =  nsdefauts.object(forKey: saved)


    let requestValues = ["send" : "A" , "IP" : ip as! String ]
    print(requestValues)

    if(WCSession.isSupported()){
        session!.sendMessage(requestValues, replyHandler: nil, errorHandler: nil)
        print("sended ip")
    }

}
```

the error is made at the "ip as! String line" how can I fix this. ?

regards Quinn

Comment: just remove ! from "as! String"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use more safe code instead

```
func Reloadip() {

    guard let ip = nsdefauts.objectForKey(saved) as? String else {
        print("there is no saved ip")
        return
    }

    let requestValues = ["send" : "A" , "IP" : ip]
    print(requestValues)

    if(WCSession.isSupported()){
        session?.sendMessage(requestValues, replyHandler: nil, errorHandler: nil)
        print("sended ip")
    }  
}
```

Comment: This is the right approach, but I'd prefer a guard over an if for something like this.

Comment: @overactor probably guard more readable; I replaced to it in my answer.